# Prove that $\lim \sup x_n = \lim \inf x_n$ iff $\lim x_n$ exists in R

Tags: real-analysis

I understand the forwards case, but not sure how to prove the backwards case since it seems so obvious.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lim x_n = x_0$, then:
\begin{align}
\exists N > 0 \  x_n &\in ( x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon) \text{ for } \ n \geq N \\
\Rightarrow \sup_{m \geq n } x_m &\in [ x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon] \\
\Rightarrow | \sup_{m \geq n } x_m - x_0 |&\leq   \epsilon < 2\epsilon \\
\Rightarrow \limsup x_n &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{m \geq n } x_m  = x_0
\end{align}
Similarly show it for the $\liminf x_n$ case.

Answer (score 1):

You may show the "backwards" direction by contradiction:
$$\lim \sup x_n \neq \lim \inf x_n \Rightarrow \lim x_n \mbox{ does not exist}$$

- Let's use the following abbreviations: $x_{sup} =\lim \sup x_n$, $x_{inf} =\lim \inf x_n$.
- Assume $x_{sup} \neq x_{inf}$ but $x_0 = \lim x_n$ still exists.
- By definition of $x_{sup}$ and $x_{inf}$ there are subsequences $x_{n_k}$ and $x_{n_m}$ with $$\lim x_{n_k} = x_{sup} \mbox{ and } \lim x_{n_m} = x_{inf}$$
- **Contradiction** to the existence of $x_0 =\lim x_n$, because each subsequence of a convergent sequence is convergent to the same limit, but $x_{sup} \neq x_{inf}$.